# Google Earth Engine: How can I perform image calculations with random values pixel by pixel?

Tags: javascript, random, pixel, raster, google-earth-engine

I would like to perform some calculations on an ee.Image pixel by pixel, however, the result calculated must obey a probabilistic Gaussian distribution, so some pixels will be modified and others not. I already coded a probabilistic function but I don't know how to apply it to each pixel in GEE. Is there any way to do that?

I already tried something like the following, but the same random number is used for every pixel, and that is not what I want.

Trial 1)

```
var result = img.where(img.lte(32 + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)),1);
```

Trial 2)

```
var result = img.expression(
    '(B1 > 32 + P) ? 1', {
    'P': Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1),
    'B1': img.select('B1')});
```

Trial 3)

```
var result = img.expression(
    'P > 10 ? 1', {
    'P': MyProbabilisticFunction(),
    'B1': img.select('B1')});
```

I also tried to use the following to generate a "probabilistic" image to perform my calculations but, since I have several classes in the same raster, the probability of the "event" is not quite right.

Trial 4)

```
var rd = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(geometry,1000,Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));
var prob = rd.draw('000000',5,0).select('vis-red');
var result = img.where(prob.eq(0),1);
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what you trying to do. Looking at the first trial, pixels where the value is less or equal to (32 + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)) puts 1, otherwise keeps the original. What are images about? some index?

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, thanks for your help. What I want to do is to go over all pixels of a mosaic and change their values, however, this change can occur or not, it will depend on the probability of an event. The value itself does not matter, what I am worried about is the probability. For example, if I have an image 10x10 and I want to change the values of 40% of its pixels, 40 random pixels will be changed and the remaining 60 will remain intact. This is the core of a probabilistic filter I am trying to code.

Comment: First of all you need to read this part of the docs: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server

Comment: For the stuff I'm working on, I'd also love to know how to do calculations pixel by pixel but in your case it might be better to somehow create an image of random values and then perform all your operations with whole images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a random value per pixel using ee.Image.random().

That said, the rest of Earth Engine doesn't work the way you're attempting to use it.  All image functions are "vectorized"; you don't ever get to work "pixel by pixel".